# polyfills.ts does not get created with ng new <project> with the angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, polyfills

I am working through some examples and learning angular. When a new project is created with the angular cli polyfills.ts is not generated. Has anyone else ran into this issue? Here is the generated file structure.

generated file structure

[image: 1]

I have tried manually adding a polyfills.ts file to the src folder but that still does not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Since version 15 polyfills.ts is not generated and it is moved directly into angular.json. So you don’t have to add it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

### You can add files in polyfills.ts using angular.json file

```
 for this goto angular.json file there you can see polyfills array
    where you can import your localize()

**"index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "@angular/localize/init"
        ],
**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When use use the latest angular v15 , the pollyfills.ts will not get created instead of that if you see that angular.json under pollyfills property you can see the zone has been added.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Ji4.png)